# Hiding icons from the Command Bar in the List web part

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, web-part, modern-experience, json-formatting

Is it possible to hide the "Folder link view" and the "i" ("open the details pane") icons from the Command Bar in the List web part? (SharePoint Online modern page).

I used JSON to format the list view and successfully hid some of the icons using the "key" properties (commandBarProps) but there are still these two and I cannot get rid of them. None of the keys seem to correspond with these two functionalities.

[image: These are the two icons I'm on about]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible using SharePoint Online JSON formatting.

SharePoint Online command bar JSON formatting does not support showing/hiding the "Switch view options" drop down and details pane options.

SharePoint Online command bar JSON formatting only supports the keys available in Microsoft official documentation at: [Command bar customization syntax reference - key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-commandbar-formatting#key)

---

You can either show or hide complete command bar from list web part using below SharePoint out of the box option, but cannot show/hide selective "Switch view options" drop down and details pane options.

[image]